# OpenGL - Object axes orientation; order of glm::translate and glm::rotate

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have found that tilting an object (by 23.4 degrees) changes the local or object space by the same angle.  The following code comes **before** the rendering loop.

```
model[1] = glm::mat4(1.0f);
...
spheres[1].m_currentPosition = glm::vec3(65.0f, 0.0f, -60.0f);
...
model[1] = glm::translate(model[1], spheres[1].m_currentPosition);
model[1] = glm::rotate(model[1], glm::radians(-23.4f), glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)));
```

In the rendering loop I have very little code other than a regular rotation about what I specified before the rendering loop as,

```
rotationAxis[1] = glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```

This will cause a rotation about an axis tilted by 23.4 degrees, the following image being a static screen shot:
[image]

Where the lines meet at world coordinates (0, 0, 0).

===

If I reverse the first two lines, viz.,

```
model[1] = glm::rotate(model[1], glm::radians(-23.4f), glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)));
model[1] = glm::translate(model[1], spheres[1].m_currentPosition);
```

The result is,
[image]

===

In the rendering loop I can rotate the sphere in place about the specified `rotationAxis[1]`, though the rotation is about a tilted 23.4 degree axis running through the blue top and bottom of the sphere in both cases.

Every other change to the (x, y, z) position of the sphere is about this now tilted frame of reference, again in both cases.

What I want is for the sphere to "orbit" in the plane of the horizontal line by calculating new (x, y, z) coordinates and then translating by the difference from the previous (x, y, z) coordinates.  This tilt would cause me to have to adjust those coordinates for the tilt.  While this is hardly impossible, I am looking for a more straightforward solution, and a better understanding of what is happening.

I have read about the order of translating and rotating in OpenGL, though changing the order does not solve my problem.

Comment: if you want ro orbit around your frame. I think you should translate your sphere to its initial position on the xAxis and then apply your rotation. Now to update its position, I would have stored the angle of rotation in a separate variable and it each update i would update it. I would use this angle in my glm::rotate and not do some delta from last known position

Comment: I have tried a variation of that, viz., "moving" the sphere to the origin and then to the new calculated (x, y, z) position.  The problem is the tilted frame of reference of the sphere.  Its y-axis, for example, is no longer aligned with that of world coordinates and the sphere moves in this inclined plane.  A second problem is I want it to move along the path of an ellipse and so tracking the angle is only part of the story.